# R: Creating a Matrix from Combinations of Column Vectors in a Data Table

Tags: r, matrix, datatable, matrix-multiplication

I have 28 columns in a data table. Columns 27 and 28 contain individual id and a choice index (so for example, individual 1 may have 5 choices and so has 5 rows in the data table and the choice index for individual 1 goes from 1 to 5; for individual 2 the choice index will go from 1 to 8 if individual 2 has 8 rows). The number of rows for each individual id varies.

This leaves 26 columns. The first 13 columns are important. I want to construct a 13x13 matrix such that:
1) We take the first column and multiply it with the 14th column, element wise, sum it over the choice and individual and record it in the 1x1 position of the 13x13 matrix.

2) We take the first column and multiply it with the 15th column, element wise, sum it over choice and individual and record it in the 1x2 position

and so on till we multiply the first column with all columns from position 14 to 26.

3) We take the second column and multiply it with the 14th column, element wise, sum it over choice and individual and record it in the 2x1 position of the 13x13 matrix....

and so on till we multiply the second column with all columns from position 14 to 26.

And I need to do this for all first 13 columns.

I am having a very hard time figuring out how to code this.

Comment: Can you provide a simplified example of this process? E.g. with a 6 column dataframe of 3 rows, and then the expected matrix output. You could do the handful of sums manually just so it's clear what you want, and it will make it easier to write the code in an answer.

Comment: If I had to have a go at this for you, is `dat <- data.frame(v1=1:3,v2=2:4,v3=3:5,v4=4:6)` and then `Map(\`*\`, dat[c("v1","v2")], list(dat[c("v3","v4")]))` what you're trying to do?

Comment: @thelatemail so with 6 column data frame, the last 2 will be the id and the choice index. So we are then left with 4 columns. I would want a 2x2 matrix. I would take the first column and element wise multiply it with 3rd and 4th columns, sum the elements of the resulting two columns separately and put these in the first row of the matrix (first column sum in 1x1 and second column sum in 1x2). Then I would take the second column and element wise multiply with the 3rd and 4th columns, repeat the procedure and put entries in 2x1 and 2x2 position in the matrix. Does this help?

Comment: @thelatemail I understand that I can code all these steps in separate lines but I want to avoid to type up the many lines of code, especially since in the future the number of columns will increase by a lot.

Comment: @thelatemail The code you gave does help because it allows me to do the multiplication out. I think I can loop over the list to sum the resulting columns. Is there an easy way to make matrix from the elements of the list. After the sum, based on your code, I will have 2 numbers for $v1 under v3 and v4 and 2 numbers for $v2 under v3 and v4. I want to put $v1 v3 in 1x1 position, $v1 v4 in 1x2 and so on. Can this be automated for a large number of variables?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you code all these steps in separate lines for your actual problem.Rather, I'm suggesting that you do it for a *very small* example like I showed, and then show the desired output for that same small example. That way, potential answerers here have something concrete to work with.

Comment: @thelatemail what you suggested worked. I managed to incorporate it in my code. Thanks. Since its a comment, not sure how I tag this as answered.